# Restrict Zooming-in (brushing) in stacked-area-chart d3js to dates only

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, charts, stacked-area-chart

By default it shows months quarterly. On brushing further, it shows all the months. ON brushing further, it shows dates. On brushing even further, it shows days. But, I want to limit brushing to dates at the max. How can I achieve that?
Following is my code:

```
draw() {
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const formatDate = (dateInput) =>{
  const today = new Date(dateInput);
  const yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  let mm:any = today.getMonth() + 1; // Months start at 0!
  let dd:any = today.getDate();
  if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
  if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
  
  const formattedDate = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
  return formattedDate;
}

const margin = { top: 60, right: 230, bottom: 50, left: 50 },
  width = 660 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);



// Parse the Data
d3.csv("./assets/date-wise-issue-type.csv").then(function (data) {

  // console.log(data);
  
  //////////
  // GENERAL //
  //////////

  // List of groups = header of the csv files
  const keys = data.columns.slice(3)

  // color palette
  const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(keys)
    .range(d3.schemeSet2);

  //stack the data?
  const stackedData = d3.stack()
    .keys(keys)
    (data)


  //////////
  // AXIS //
  //////////
  // console.log(data);
  // Add X axis
  const x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { const xInput = formatDate(d.date); return new Date(xInput); }))
    .range([0, width]);
  console.log(d3.extent(data, function (d) { const xInput = formatDate(d.date); return xInput; }));
  const xAxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5))

  // Add X axis label:
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("x", width)
    .attr("y", height + 40)
    .text("Time (months)");

  // Add Y axis label:
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -20)
    .text("")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  
  // Add Y axis
  const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 7000])
    .range([height, 0]);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5))



  //////////s
  // BRUSHING AND CHART //
  //////////

  // Add a clipPath: everything out of this area won't be drawn.
  const clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);

  // Add brushing
  const brush = d3.brushX()                 // Add the brush feature using the d3.brush function
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .scaleExtent([0.1, 10]) // initialise the brush area: start at 0,0 and finishes at width,height: it means I select the whole graph area
    .on("end", updateChart) // Each time the brush selection changes, trigger the 'updateChart' function

  // Create the scatter variable: where both the circles and the brush take place
  const areaChart = svg.append('g')
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

  // Area generator
  const area = d3.area()
    .x(function (d) { return x(new Date(d.data.date)); })
    .y0(function (d) { return y(d[0]); })
    .y1(function (d) { return y(d[1]); })
  
  // Show the areas
  areaChart
    .selectAll("mylayers")
    .data(stackedData)
    .join("path")
    .attr("class", function (d) { return "myArea " + d.key })
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.key); })
    .attr("d", area)

  // Add the brushing
  areaChart
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush);

  let idleTimeout
  function idled() { idleTimeout = null; }

  // A function that update the chart for given boundaries
  function updateChart(event, d) {

    const extent = event.selection

    // If no selection, back to initial coordinate. Otherwise, update X axis domain
    if (!extent) {
      if (!idleTimeout) return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, 350); // This allows to wait a little bit
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return new Date(d.date); }))
      // console.log("if", d3.extent(data, function (d) { return new Date(d.date); }));
      
    } else {
      x.domain([x.invert(extent[0]), x.invert(extent[1])])
      // console.log("else", extent);
      areaChart.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null) // This remove the grey brush area as soon as the selection has been done
    }

    // Update axis and area position
    xAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5))
    areaChart
      .selectAll("path")
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .attr("d", area)
  }



  //////////
  // HIGHLIGHT GROUP //
  //////////

  // What to do when one group is hovered
  const highlight = function (event, d) {
    // reduce opacity of all groups
    d3.selectAll(".myArea").style("opacity", .1)
    // expect the one that is hovered
    d3.select("." + d).style("opacity", 1)
  }

  // And when it is not hovered anymore
  const noHighlight = function (event, d) {
    d3.selectAll(".myArea").style("opacity", 1)
  }

  //////////
  // LEGEND //
  //////////

  // Add one dot in the legend for each name.
  const size = 20
  svg.selectAll("myrect")
    .data(keys)
    .join("rect")
    .attr("x", 400)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return 10 + i * (size + 5) }) // 100 is where the first dot appears. 25 is the distance between dots
    .attr("width", size)
    .attr("height", size)
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d) })
    .on("mouseover", highlight)
    .on("mouseleave", noHighlight)

  // Add one dot in the legend for each name.
  svg.selectAll("mylabels")
    .data(keys)
    .join("text")
    .attr("x", 400 + size * 1.2)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return 10 + i * (size + 5) + (size / 2) }) // 100 is where the first dot appears. 25 is the distance between dots
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d) })
    .text(function (d) { return d })
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
    .on("mouseover", highlight)
    .on("mouseleave", noHighlight)

})}

draw();
```

Following is the link for the csv:
https://file.io/xlGjENteto4b